# How do I find the subspace of $P_{2}$ from the following subsets?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

One of the following is a subspace of $P_{2}$.

A. $W= \{ax^2+bx+c\mid a+b+c=1\}$

B. $W= \{ax^2+bx+c\mid a+b+c=0\}$

C. $W= \{ax^2+bx+c\mid a \geq 0\}$

D. $W= \{ax^2+bx+c \mid b,c \geq 0\}$

So it's either $B, C$, or $D$ because the zero vector condition won't work on $A$. What I don't understand is the difference between $C$ and $D$. How does having 'a' greater than or equal zero differ from having '$b$' and '$c$' greater than or equal zero? Can someone please explain how it works? This concept is a bit new to me and I couldn't find any examples of this particular case online.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that a subspace must be closed under multiplication by a scalar such as $-1$

Comment: ...What is "p2"?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant a polynomial of degree 2

Comment: @Ottavio Likely the space consisting of polynomials with degree at most $2$.

Comment: Sorry, never seen that notation before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does having 'a' greater than or equal zero differ from having 'b' and 'c' greater than or equal zero? Can someone please explain how it works?

So, for example, consider the polynomials
$$
p_1(x) = 2x^2 + 3x + 4,\\
p_2(x) = -3x^2 + 4x + 5,\\
p_3(x) = 0x^2 - 5x + 6,\\
p_4(x) = -5x^2 + 6x - 7.
$$
The polynomials $p_1$ and $p_3$ are elements of the set described in C because the $x^2$ coefficient (the "$a$" coefficient) is non-negative. The polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2$ are in the set described in D because the other coefficients (the "$b$" and "$c$" coefficients) are non-negative. $p_4$ is in neither set because it is not true that $a \geq 0$, and it is also not true that we have both $b \geq 0$ and $c \geq 0$.

Comment: I understand. But do either of these sets satisfy the three conditions to be a subspace of a polynomial of degree 2?

Comment: @ReimOss What do you think? You've already checked whether they have the zero vector. From there, the next easy condition to check is whether the set is closed under scalar multiplication. Are these sets closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: I don't think they're closed under scalar multiplication. If the scalar constant is a negative number then either of these sets will prove wrong. Is that right?

Comment: @Reim That's exactly right

Answer (score -1):

**Hint to answer the title question:**

A subspace must be closed under multiplication by a scalar such as $−1$.